# msgpack-java & java.nio.SocketChannel

Tags: java, nio, socketchannel, msgpack

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to setup a non-blocking IO (network sockets) using msgpack.  The write portion is trivial since msgpack can generate a `ByteBuffer` fairly easily, but I can't figure out how to do non-blocking read into the MessagePack object.  Looking at `MessagePack.read()` there are three primary options... `read(InputStream in)`, `read(byte[] b)` and `read(ByteBuffer b)`.  All of which are blocking operations.

The reason i'm trying to go to a non-blocking transport is my server could need hundreds of simultaneous long-lived connections.

Any suggestions?  It seems on my googling that most people just use msgpack with blocking IO.  The only option I can think of is

Comment: One quite efficent way I use, is that you send the size of the msg pack bytes you want to send, then you fill up a `ByteBuffer` with this until you red all bytes you actually need, if you have those you know you are able to unpack it, does that help?